# Xcode 4.4 storyboarods, how to change first view in Tab Bar

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a storyboard with 5 tabbed views. It always defaults with first. I'd like it to be the third view that's always displayed first when the app comes up.

How do I do that? I couldn't figure it out from the Storyboard interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. found the answer:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
  tabBar.selectedIndex = 2;  // zero based index of desired default tab to launch with.
  return YES;
}
```